# TSQL - divide rows into groups based on one field

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

This is modified version of my earlier question: [TSQL equally divide resultset to groups and update them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059119/tsql-equally-divide-resultset-to-groups-and-update-them)

I have my database with 2 tables like so:

Orders table has data like below:

```
OrderID    OperatorID    GroupID        OrderDesc    Status    Cash    ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1             1          1      small_order         1     300 
      2             1          1    another_order         1       0 
      3             1          2      xxxxxxxxxxx         2    1000 
      5             2          2      yyyyyyyyyyy         2     150 
      9             5          1      xxxxxxxxxxx         1      50 
     10          NULL          2      xxxxxxxxxxx         1     150 
     11          NULL          3      xxxxxxxxxxx         1     -50 
     12             4          1      xxxxxxxxxxx         1     200
```

Operators table:

```
OperatorID    Name    GroupID    Active
---------------------------------------
      1       John          1         1
      2       Kate          1         1
      4       Jack          2         1
      5       Will          1         0
      6        Sam          3         0
```

I'm able to equally divide my recordset into equally groups using below query:

```
SELECT o.*, op.operatorName AS NewOperator, op.operatorID AS NewOperatorId
FROM (SELECT o.*, (ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY newid()) % numoperators) + 1 AS randseqnum
      FROM Orders o CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) AS numoperators FROM operators WHERE operators.active=1) op
      WHERE o.status in (1,3)
     ) o JOIN
     (SELECT op.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY newid()) AS seqnum
      FROM Operators op WHERE op.active=1
     ) op
     ON o.randseqnum = op.seqnum ORDER BY o.orderID
```

Demo available at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ff47b/1

Using script from above I can divide Orders to (almost) equal groups but based on number or Orders for Operator, but I need to modify it so that it will assign Operators to Orders based on sum or `Cash` for orders.

For example:

If I have 6 Orders with `Cash` values: 300, 0, 50, 150, -50, 200 they sum gives 650.
My script should assign to 3 Operators random 2 Orders with random sum of `Cash` for Orders.
What I would like to get is to assign for example 300,-50 to operator1, 200, 0 to second and 150, 50 to third.
Hope this sound clear :)

Here is example output that I expect to get:

```
ORDERID  OPERATORID  GROUPID    DESCRIPTION  STATUS  CASH  NEWOPERATORID
------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1           1        1    small_order       1   300              2
      2           1        1  another_order       1     0              1
      9           5        1    xxxxxxxxxxx       1    50              4
     10      (null)        2    xxxxxxxxxxx       1   150              4
     11      (null)        3    xxxxxxxxxxx       1   -50              2
     12           4        1    xxxxxxxxxxx       1   200              1
```

**How can I (if I can at all) assign Operators to my Orders so that sum or `Cash` will be closest to average**

Comment: Your table data at top does not match your example data at the bottom, and neither of them match the data in the SQL Fiddle. Please make your example simple and consistent, and provide desired output.

Comment: @RedFilter - Sorry for that, I've already fixed my question and updated link to sqlfiddle so could You remove -1 from my question?

Comment: @Misiu, you say "My script will assign to 3 Operators random 2 Orders with random sum of Cash for Orders" but later at the bottom of your question you say "How can I (if I can at all) assign Operators to my Orders so that sum or Cash will be closest to average?"   -- I think these contradict each other, although I believe what you are asking is a combination of the two, i.e. "How can I distribute the orders, based on cash values, to new operators so that each operator has SUM(CASH) as close as possible to the average CASH among all operators? Each operator can have any order."

Comment: @dev_etter That's the right question :) But I would like that each operator to have sum of cash values as close as possible to average, but also number of orders should be even (as close as possible), so that it won't distribute one big order to one and 10 to second because sum is almost the same. It should assign operators by sum of their orders and number of those orders. Hope this clears a bit whole situation :)

Comment: This is not an easy problem (the time and memory will grow exponentially as the number of operators and orders increase)  You can reduce the complexity of the problem if you are willing to accept a "good enough" solution, instead of the solution that is as "close as possible" to distributing the orders evenly.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this right, could you get the result you want by ordering the Cash column by the biggest, then the smallest, then the next biggest, then the next smallest, etc. Like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CASE WHEN CashOrder % 2 = 1 then Cash else -Cash END) as splitCash
```

where you've provided CashOrder lower in the query with

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER by CASH) as CashOrder
```

Then you specify each of your operators depending on this split value, ie (for three operators):

```
splitCash%3 +1
```